# In Flutter, how to get List<String> from Firestore array. It only returns List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter

I want to get `List<String>` from fireStore array. It only returns `List<dynamic>`. How to fix it?

In my product list there are other variable and only 1 list.

This is code of get from firestore.

```
 Stream<List<Product>> getAllProducts() {
    return _firebaseFirestore
        .collection('products')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Product.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();
    });
  }
```

This is my Product detail.

```
class Product extends Equatable {
  final String name;
  final String category;
  final String imageUrl;
  final int price;
  final bool isRecommanded;
  final bool isPopular;
  final String? detail;
  final List<String>? storage;

  const Product(
      {required this.name,
      this.detail,
      this.storage,
      required this.category,
      required this.imageUrl,
      required this.price,
      required this.isRecommanded,
      required this.isPopular});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        name,
        category,
        imageUrl,
        price,
        isRecommanded,
        isPopular,
        detail,
        storage
      ];

  static Product fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    Product product = Product(
        name: snap['name'],
        category: snap['category'],
        imageUrl: snap['imageUrl'],
        detail: snap['detail'],
        price: snap['price'],
        isRecommanded: snap['isRecommanded'],
        isPopular: snap['isPopular'],
        storage: [snap['storage']] as List<String>);
    
    return product;
  }
```

This is my bloc patten.

```
class ProductBloc extends Bloc<ProductEvent, ProductState> {
  final ProductRepository _productRepository;
  StreamSubscription? _productSubscription;
  ProductBloc({required ProductRepository productRepository})
      : _productRepository = productRepository,
        super(ProductLoading()) {
    on<ProductEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (event is LoadProducts) {
        _productSubscription?.cancel();
        _productSubscription = _productRepository
            .getAllProducts()
            .listen((products) => add(UpdateProducts(products)));
      }
      if (event is UpdateProducts) {
        emit(ProductSuccess(products: event.products));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can use `cast` method from the list:

```dart
final List<dynamic> dynamicList = ["test"];
final List<String> strings = dynamicList.cast<String>();
print(strings.toString());
```

So `fromSnapshot` will be like:

```dart
static Product fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    return Product(
        name: snap['name'],
        category: snap['category'],
        imageUrl: snap['imageUrl'],
        detail: snap['detail'],
        price: snap['price'],
        isRecommanded: snap['isRecommanded'],
        isPopular: snap['isPopular'],
        storage: (snap['storage'] as List<dynamic>).cast<String>(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast

This error still exist sir. I tried that you say.but still doesn't working.
@Luis

Comment: @KoOo can you put a breakpoint to see what is the runtimeType of `snap['storage']`?

Comment: And not just that, but it is possible to see the `snap['storage']` content? The value must have only String values